# Reading a line from STDIN in J

Tags: stdin, readline, j

**TL;DR how do I read a line of characters from stdin in J without consuming all of stdin?** I am looking for a portable method of doing this.

I've been trying to make an *interactive* J program that reads a line of input from the user. During my research, I came across [this page](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/input_and_output.htm), which says (emph. added):

> J's native file operations are file-oriented rather than stream-oriented; that is, they read an entire file at a time, and there is no notion of a 'current file pointer', or a newline character, or a readline verb that returns just one record.  **Such facilities are easy to write**, but it is usually better to work with entire files at a time, just as for ordinary computation J works with whole arrays at a time.  Read your file in, split it into records, and work on the list of records.

However, I am at a loss for writing such a utility. The task would be rendered trivial if J had a `getchar` function, but as far as I can tell, the only way to read input is to consume all input through the foreign call `1!:1(3)` (or `stdin''`). This is hardly the desired solution, as I want to be able to interact with the user's input.

For example, let's say I wanted to replicate the behaviour of this Python 3 program:

```python
print("Enter grade: ")
grade = int(input())
if grade > 90:
    print("Good job!")
else:
    print(":/")

print("Enter some text: ")
text = input()
print("Reversed: " + text[::-1])
```

This could roughly be translated in J as:

```
getgrade := 3 : 0
  grade =. ". y
  if. grade > 90 do.  echo 'Good job!'
  else.               echo ':/'
  end.
)

echo 'Enter grade: '
getgrade readline ''
echo 'Enter some text: '
echo 'Reversed: ' , |. readline ''
```

Assuming, of course, the proper definition of `readline`.

### Thoughts

I thought that maybe I could use J's `shell` or `spawn` command to invoke an executable that reads a line. However, `shell` requires the input to be passed from the verb itself, and I cannot make `spawn` work on my J installation, though I doubt it would produce the correct behaviour.

Comment: [This](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/User:Ric_Sherlock/Temp/InteractivePrompt) might help.

Comment: @Eelvex `load 'misc'` doesn't seem to do anything for me, even after `install 'all'`.Additionally, the verb `prompt=: 3 : '1!:1]1 [ ((2) 1!:2~ ])y'` fails to provide any source of interactivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this

> Such facilities are easy to write

is in the spirit of *"such facilities are easy to implement in the core language"*.

I can't find a satisfying way to implement what you want. The following might help a bit.

#### 1. Make a qt-app or a `lab`

There are a lot of form and prompt utilities in jqt. 
The [window driver](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/Window_Driver/Command_Reference) can do many things.

#### 2. Use `general/misc/prompt`

Make a script:

```
load'general/misc/prompt'
main =: 3 : 0
 a =: prompt 'Enter grade: '
 echo 'Grade entered: ',a
)
```

but then you will have to use REPL

```
 load'yourscript'
 main ''
```

#### 3. Use a wrapper script.

```
--- wrap.sh ---
#!/usr/bin/env bash
j <<EOF
+/ $(read -p 'Grades: ' k; echo $k)
EOF
---
./wrap.sh
Grades: 3 5 9
17
```

Comment: Or instruct your users to terminate their input with `^D` and make your life easier.